# Graph API requests for guest users in Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-ad-graph-api

I wanted to know how can we make graph API calls for guest users in Azure AD. I am able to achieve it for internal users using the API examples given [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations) but the same calls are not working on guest user. Is there any difference in the way the requests need to be made?

Comment: What exactly do you mean they are not working? What calls?

Comment: I mean the graph API calls on users described here(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations) . For example the API call for getting user details:

https://graph.windows.net/<tenantName>/users/<userid>?api-version=2013-04-05
This works in the case of internal users. But in case of external users it returns a 400 response code.

Comment: In addition to the status code you should check the response body, it might have some more details.

Comment: For me the query you mentioned works with api-version=1.6.

Comment: @juunas sorry the response code I got was 404 and not 400.
The error response I am getting is :
Resource 'userid' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.

Comment: Are you trying to find them with their user principal name (login name) or their object id? Because their user principal name is not the same in your directory, and it's one that can't be used in the URL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Guest accounts in your tenant will have a different user principal name than the UPN they have in their home tenant. You should be able to see evidence of this by querying all the users in your tenant, and finding the external users which have a 'modified' user principal name, usually with "EXT".

You can see a direct example of this in our Demo Tenant [here](https://graphexplorer.cloudapp.net/Home/Index/DemoCompany?UrlRequest=GET&text=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.windows.net%2Fgraphdir1.onmicrosoft.com%2Fusers%2F19300e9e-09c0-40ed-bd07-bfe703c056d7)

```
"userPrincipalName": "djayachandran.cw_mmm.com#EXT#@GraphDir1.onmicrosoft.com",
```

It seems like you will need to query for these users using other properties where their old UPN is not changed, like the 'mail' property. Ultimately, you want to find the ObjectId of the user you are interested in, and use that as your key to find the user information. You should be able to get the object id from the token of the signed in user.

Let me know if this helps!
Thanks,
Shawn Tabrizi

Comment: I am able to do a get operation for the user with the object ID. But after authentication I will only have the username of the user, so how do I get the object Id using the accessToken?

I am facing troubles with all APIs related to password. Reset password and change password won't work for guest users in my tenant as they are authenticated and their passwords are stored in their own tenant. So the question is how do these users then reset or change their passwords?

Comment: The idea with external users is that their identities at not managed by you, they are managed by their own organizations. To reset passwords, they would either ask their admins, or, if they are enabled for self-service password reset, would reset their own passwords.

Answer (score 0):

@Shawn Tabrizi's answer above helped me achieve what I needed (get Azure AD group info for logged in user).

To get the user AD ObjectID from the identity claims, I used this:

```cs
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;

namespace HealthcareEfficiencyService_webApp.Helpers
{
    public class ClaimsHelper
    {
        private readonly static string objectIdClaimsType = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier";

        public static string getAdObjectId(ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity)
        {
            return claimsIdentity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == objectIdClaimsType).Value;
        }
    }
}
```